# Problems with premission and wifi in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, wifimanager

I want to get some information about the wifi that i am connected to, but i keep getting this error about my premissions, but i guess they should be alright. Can you help me out here?

The first line in my `logcat` describes the problem. The line is the one where i call `wifi.getConnectionInfo();`

My java code:

```
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


//    private ConnectivityReceiver receiver = null;
//    private TextView txtNetworkInfo = null;
      private WifiManager wifi;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            wifi.getConnectionInfo();
//              startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CheckService.class));
        }

    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CheckService.class));
        }

    });
}
}
```

And my logcat-

```
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jesper.soundchange/com.jesper.soundchange.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10067 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10067 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE.
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1247)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1235)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.getDhcpInfo(IWifiManager.java:754)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.getDhcpInfo(WifiManager.java:712)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at com.jesper.soundchange.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)  
11-15 18:08:37.583: E/AndroidRuntime(28200):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
```

My manifest-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jesper.soundchange"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <service
    android:name=".CheckService"
    android:label="My Service" >
</service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out. I misspelled uses-permission in the two last lines :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided:

a) make sure that you are editing the right manifest.xml (located in **bin/res**)

b) i dont see your start and end tags of manifest. ( )
But i am pretty sure that you have them there.

c) I cannot spot any coding errors in your current context